# Container for drag n drop different size of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to make a container for images with different sizes the sizes will be a multiple of a number (example.: 25x25px 50x50px 75x50px etc.)
I need ideas how can i make a droppable container for these draggable images. I don't want to allow to drop images on top of each other, or to loll out from the container.
(I don't know if i used the good words so if you don't understand check this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqcMW.png)
If somebody has any ideas or demos, it would be nice. :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

didnt completely understand your question but.DO you want the user to drag and drop images to the containers for image upload facility
then you can create a container of one size and after the upload of that image is complete you could some other container for other image size

Comment: No, those are static images on the site, with drag function

Answer (score 0):

interesting task, this is just some inspiration how you could hold the information on the page, you'll have to find out yourself if this is a suitable way to solve this .

You could create a hidden HTML-structure dynamicly depending on your images  by iterating over them and for each one you create a dom-element containing the information you need to fit you task.

for example all you images are draggable and have the class `.images`, and  an unique id `#img1...` and your hidden-structure is an `<ul id="imgholder" style="display:none;>` somewhere in your dom.

append hidden li for each image with the info you need, i guess width, height and an id

```
$('.images').each(function() {
var width = $('this').attr('width');
var height = $('this').attr('height')
var id = $('this').attr('id');
$('#imgholder').append('<li class="imgdata" id="'+id+'" data-id="'+width+'" >'+height+'</li>');
```

after this you can  use the info to create your droppable elements

```
    var $item = $(this);
    var id = $item.attr('id');
    var width = $item.data('id'); 
    var height = $item.text();
   /*  append some div's to your desired container e.G .dropcontainer*/
    $('.dropcontainer').append('<div class="droppable" style="position:relative;foat:left;width:'+width+'px;height'+height+'px;" id="drop_'+id+'"></div>";
```

Now you have a dropbox for every image, it's up to you how to let this look elegant,
as you can find for each image the matching container `#img1 -> #drop_img1`, by starting the drag event you could add a class to the dropbox matching to the image, adding a blinking border or ... , for make this look better you could let the div's without height and with until starting draggable event and add them only to the matching container, i guess this would look cool as it floats left..

have fun